# Perl Substitution Issue

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I am trying to replace any spaces after > except for spaces after `</a>`. How can I do this using the Perl substitution operator?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to replace them with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the spaces after `>` except `</a>`, you can use this:

```
$subject =~ s%(?<!</a)>\s*%>%mg;
```

**How does it work?**

1. The `%` are the delimiters for the regex. They don't participate in the match.
2. The `(?<!</a)` is a negative lookbehind that asserts "at this position in the string, what is behind me is not `</a`".
3. After asserting this, we match a `>` and a whitespace character.

Therefore, we have matched a `>` string but not the wrong one.

The replacement, indicated by `%>%`, is just a `>`, allowing us to get rid of the whitespace character.

Comment: Thanks so much! Could you explain how the code works and I understand some regular expression stuff but not all of your code.

Comment: @WebStuck You're very welcome, it was a pleasure. Added an explanation to the answer. Let me know if you have any questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you as it will only replace a space that follows a `>` and not a `</a>`

```
(?<=\>)(?<!\<\/a\>)[[:space:]]
```

**[REGEX101](http://regex101.com/r/gB4iW1)**

**PERL:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
        $_ =~ s/(?<=\>)(?<!\<\/a\>)[[:space:]]/REPLACEMENT/gm;
        print $_;
}

__DATA__
> 
> Test
</a> TEST
<s m> TEST
```

**Output:**

```
>REPLACEMENT
>REPLACEMENTTest
</a> TEST
<s m>REPLACEMENTTEST
```